# How can I remove green streaks from cherry lumber?

Tags: finishing

This cherry lumber has some faint, but definitely noticeable, green streaks.

[image: green-streaked cherry]
<sup>Source: me</sup>

I'd like to give the piece I make with these boards a natural-colored finish, but not if the streaks will show. How can I eliminate, or at least reduce, the visibility of these green streaks? Would a dark stain hide them, or could I remove them before putting on something like Danish oil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how deep they are, but I suspect they are very shallow.  So I would either run them through my planer at a minimal setting, or use a hand sander to sand off the discoloration.  When my cut lumber sits outdoors drying it gets discolored strongly, but it still only takes a couple passes of the planer to have nice clean beautiful wood.

Otherwise, yes a darker stain would likely hide it as well.  I personally would try one of the two ways I listed to remove it first though.